# Testing association between two categorical variables, with repeated experiments

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, biostatistics, contingency-tables

Say you are counting sharks and whales in the Atlantic and Indian occeans and want to check if eg sharks prefer the Atlantic and whales the Indian occean, as described in the example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html). But instead of just total counts (eg sharks observed in the atlantic), you keep counts for individual days. For example:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+  
|        | Atlantic1 | Atlantic2 | Atlantic3 | Indian1 | Indian2 | Indian3 |  
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+  
| whales |         9 |        3  |       11  |       4 |       5 |       6 |  
| sharks |         2 |        5  |        1  |      10 |       5 |       8 |  
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

You could take the means to get a 2*2 contingency table, and proceed as in link to the fisher exact test above, but wouldn't you then remove valuable information about the variance? Is there a way to test for association using all the information in the table above?