# Measure association in contingency table based on repeated measures?

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, chi-squared-test, assumptions, contingency-tables

I would like to show that/whether there is an association between two categorical variables shown in this frequency table (Code to reproduce the table at the end of the post):

```
               Success_trials:
Condition:     0    1    2    3
  Training A   57   22   66 2195
  Training B  426   94  135 1685
```

The table is based on **repeated measures** from 45 participants, who each practiced 104 different items (half in Training A and half in Training B). Each Participant/Item combination was counted once (so contributed to exactly one cell in this table), so there are 45*104 observations.

**Is it correct that these data violate the assumption of independent observations for a ChiSquare test** because some of the counts in the table stem from the same participant? I was wondering if this might not be the case because each ItemxParticipant observation only counts towards one cell.

If **ChiSquare** is not an option, **which test would be appropriate** to test whether these two variables are statistically significantly associated? 
If possible, I am looking for a simple test because this is a minor side result, so I don't want to do a full mixed model etc. I could treat Success_trials as quantitative variable and then use aggregated data per participant for a t-test, but it would be nicer if I could report on the association between the categorical variables.

```
structure(c(57L, 426L, 22L, 94L, 66L, 135L, 2195L, 1685L), .Dim = c(2L,4L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Condition = c("Training A", "Training B"), Success_trials = c("0", "1", "2", "3")), .Names = c("Condition", "Success_trials")), class = "table")
```

*Related questions about this in the discussionboard:*

I found a number of related questions, all unanswered:

- [An appropriate alternative to chi2 for paired, categorical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222799/an-appropriate-alternative-to-chi2-for-paired-categorical-data-tables-larger-t?rq=1)
  [Frequency with repeated measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86752/frequency-with-repeated-measures)
- [how-to-test-the-independence-of-two-categorical-variables-with-repeated-observations?](http://How%20to%20test%20the%20independence%20of%20two%20categorical%20variables%20with%20repeated%20observations?) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180509/how-to-test-the-independence-of-two-categorical-variables-with-repeated-observat?rq=1
- [testing-association-between-two-categorical-variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84201/testing-association-between-two-categorical-variables-with-repeated-experiments?rq=1)-this one is
  about sharks!

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I understand that

- there are a total of 45 participants;
- each participants practices 52 items in Training A and 52 items in Training B;
- you are interested in comparing the effect of Training A vs. the effect of Training B on the practice success of the participants.

What I don't understand, is

- what "Success_trials" is supposed to describe;
- how the practice performance of each participant per item is measured;
- whether the participants were randomly sampled from some population of interest.

This additional information would be needed for an answer to the question of what test can be applied. Still, some things can be said:

- Yes, the data violate the assumption of independence. Intuitively, you can see the problem arising from this violation by noting that, in theory, all the observations in "Success_trials" 0 to 3 could come from as few as 3 people (ceiling((57+22+66)/45)) in Training A and from as few as 13 people (ceiling((426 + 94 + 135)/45)) in Training B.
- You could of course still perform a statistical test, for example by using the approach you suggest and calculate the average success rate of each participant in both Training A and Training B and then perfom a Wilcoxon signed-rank test (as you have a pair of success rates for each participant in Training A and B). However, note that in the absence of random sampling of the study participants you are just drawing an inference on whether the effect of Training A is different from the effect of Training B *in this particular group of people*. In short, you are testing the null that there is no difference in effect between the two training regimes and that any differences your are observing are just the result of the natural variability within the 45 people practicing your items.